# How to align a plot and a table in a html page?

Tags: html, jinja2

This is my html file content:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>MyApp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
          <div align="center">
          <img  src= {{url}}"/>
          <table align="center">{{table}}</table>
          </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my expected output:
[image]

I think this format is a jinja template but I toke this structure from a html doc and changed it a bit. [You can find it here Jinja template](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/)

Could you please tell me how to align the left sides of both table and graph(they both should remain in the center of the page).

Comment: Have you tried putting align="left" on the table instead of center?

Comment: Yes but it puts both on the left side of page, which I just want to align them in the center of page

Comment: That's not plain HTML

Comment: It's a translation of jinja template but I toke this structure from a html doc and changed it a bit. [Jinja template](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/)